# Getting all rows excluding a SQL resultset

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the data in the database

```
robot_id    sequence_no x            y
ABC1234E    1         8888         9999
ABC1234E    2         8888         9999
ABC1234E    3         8888         9999 
ABC1234E    4         8888         9999
 BBC1        1        8888         9999
  BBC2      1         8888         9999
  BBC2      2         8888         9999
  BBC3      1         8888         9999
```

.....

I wish to exclude this resultset:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE robot_id=ABC1234E AND sequence_no='1'
```

This is what I should get:

```
  robot_id      sequence_no           x             y
ABC1234E                2         8888         9999
ABC1234E                3         8888         9999 
ABC1234E                4         8888         9999
    BBC1        1         8888         9999
  BBC2      1         8888         9999
  BBC2      2         8888         9999
  BBC3      1         8888         9999
```

.....

robot id and sequence_no are the primary keys in this table

Comment: Oralce/sql server/mysql?

Comment: What happens if there is robot_id ABC1234X and sequence_no 2? Include or exclude?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović As question is write, I suppose that he want to include it

Comment: @DonCallisto All the answers concentrate on sequence_no because there is only one robot_id. Correct answer should include `or` if OP wants to include record I proposed.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović : I've updated my answer at the same time you've commented.

Comment: the main idea is to get all other data except robotid=ABC1234E and sequence_no =1, there are some other robot_id in the tables too

Comment: @user1663380 if you take a look at my answer, you'll find that fits your needs

Comment: Think of it as `where not (robot_id = 'ABC1234E' AND sequence_no = 1)` which translates to `where robot_id <> 'ABC1234E' OR sequence_no <> 1)`

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović is what I've done in my answer ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the fun of it, you can also use the (ANSI standard) `except` clause (`minus` in Oracle) which kind of "resembles" the way you asked the question:

```
select *
from the_table
except
select *
from the_table
where robot_id = 'ABC1234E' 
  and sequence_no = 1;
```

This will probably be slower than the other solutions though - but I thought I'd include it for completeness.

(Note that character literals have to be enclosed in single quotes and numbers don't - just the other way round as you did in your question)

Comment: @user1663380: you should have mentioned that you are limited by using MySQL

Comment: @user1663380: yes (and Postgres, and DB2 and Oracle...) I think MySQL is the only one not supporting that (as with many other modern SQL features)

Answer (score 2):

You will use your query except you just change the `WHERE` clause to say you want all `robot_id=ABC1234E` and `WHERE sequence_no does not equal = 1`. If you have only one `robot_id` value you would use:

so your query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE robot_id='ABC1234E' 
   AND sequence_no !=1
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE robot_id='ABC1234E' 
   AND sequence_no <> 1
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf116/3)

But if your data will include additional `robot_id` values than you can use:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where not exists (SELECT sequence_no
                FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE robot_id='ABC1234E' 
                  and sequence_no = 1
                   and t1.robot_id = t2.robot_id
                   and t1.sequence_no = t2.sequence_no)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ea7e/13)

Comment: by the way robot_id='ABC1234E' isn't the only data in there. This is the idea about excluding one row of results and retrieving all other results

Comment: @user1663380 : I suppose that ... So take a look to my answer

Comment: @user1663380 with the new sample data you posted, I updated my query, please see my edit and working demo.

Comment: @bluefeet, tried your sql query, some rows are still left out, the above table isn't the complete table, it's just an example of my idea

Comment: @user1663380 I am not sure what you are seeing, I expanded the data sample -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07a7f/1  and it is working

Comment: @bluefeet why is there a need to use t1.robotid=t2.robotid, and t1.sequenceno=t2.sequenceno?  works for this table, but wonder if it will work for other tables?

Comment: @user1663380 those lines are used to related the data from outer table the call in the `WHERE` clause, when using `NOT EXISTS` I used those two fields because those are the two values we are trying to exclude. You might have to change the fields on another tables, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE robot_id=ABC1234E AND sequence_no<>'1'
```

if you have a much more complex query, you can use a 'minus' query depending on your RDBMS.
like here : http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE robot_id NOT LIKE 'ABC1234E' 
 OR sequence_no <> 1
```